# mysql query - optimizing existing MAX-MIN query for a huge table

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa-2.0

I have a more or less good working query (concerning to the result) but it takes about 45seconds to be processed. That's definitely too long for presenting the data in a GUI.
So my demand is to find a much faster/efficient query (something around a few milliseconds would be nice)
My data table has something around <strike>3000</strike> ~2,619,395 entries and is still growing.

Schema:

```
num | station | fetchDate             | exportValue | error
1   | PS1     | 2010-10-01 07:05:17   | 300         | 0
2   | PS2     | 2010-10-01 07:05:19   | 297         | 0
923 | PS1     | 2011-11-13 14:45:47   | 82771       | 0
```

Explanation

- the exportValue is always incrementing
- the exportValue represents the actual absolute value
- in my case there are 10 stations
- every ~15 minutes 10 new entries are written to the table
- error is just an indicator for a proper working station

Working query:

```
select
    YEAR(fetchDate), station, Max(exportValue)-MIN(exportValue)
from
    registros
where
    exportValue > 0 and error = 0 
group
    by station, YEAR(fetchDate)
order 
    by YEAR(fetchDate), station
```

Output:

```
Year | station | Max-Min
2008 | PS1     | 24012
2008 | PS2     | 23709
2009 | PS1     | 28102
2009 | PS2     | 25098
```

My thoughts on it:

1. writing several queries with between statements like 'between 2008-01-01 and 2008-01-02' to fetch the MIN(exportValue) and between 2008-12-30 and 2008-12-31' to grab the MAX(exportValue) - Problem: a lot of queries and the problem with having no data in a specified time range (it's not guaranteed that there will be data)
2. limiting the resultset to my 10 stations only with using order by MIN(fetchDate) - problem: takes also a long time to process the query

Additional Info:
I'm using the query in a JAVA Application. That means, it would be possible to do some post-processing on the resultset if necessary. (JPA 2.0)

Any help/approaches/ideas are very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding suitable indexes will help. 
2 compound indexes will speed things up significantly:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name ADD INDEX (error, exportValue);
ALTER TABLE tbl_name ADD INDEX (station, fetchDate);
```

Comment: Thanks for this good hint with creating indexes. I used google to find some more information on it -> http://www.sitepoint.com/optimizing-mysql-application (if someone is interested in it). My query is now processed in ~5seconds. Unfortunately only when using the sql console of phpMyAdmin and not when processing the query from Java with JPA 2.0 :/ (but I will take a look at that)

Answer (score 0):

This query running on 3000 records should be extremely fast.

Suggestions:

- do You have PK set on this table? station, fetchDate?
- add indexes; You should experiment and try with indexes as rich.okelly suggested in his answer
- depending on experiments with indexes, try breaking your query into multiple statements - in one stored procedure; this way You will not loose time in network traffic between multiple queries sent from client to mysql
- You mentioned that You tried with separate queries and there is a problem when there is no data for particular month; it is regular case in business applications, You should handle it in a "master query" (stored procedure or application code)
- guess fetchDate is current date and time at the moment of record insertion; consider keeping previous months data in sort of summary table with fields: year, month, station, max(exportValue), min(exportValue) - this means that You should insert summary records in summary table at the end of each month; deleting, keeping or moving detail records to separate table is your choice

Since your table is rapidly growing (every 15 minutes) You should take the last suggestion into account. Probably, there is no need to keep detailed history at one place. Archiving data is process that should be done as part of maintenance.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I wrote a wrong value for the amount of entries .. it's thousand times more than 3k .. :/ (data from 2008 till now added every 15min for each day from sunrise to sunset [database contents data from some photovoltaic stations]). I forgot to mention, that the database belongs to a client. So I can't really modify it with adding new fields etc. But I tested the indexes stuff on my local dump. Queries written in the sql browser of phpMyAdmin are faster processed, but in my JavaApplication with JPA 2.0 not :(

Comment: You are welcome, unfortunately I didn't help. I am really sorry but I am not familiar with JPA, guess that JPA is not executing your query as you wrote it. Maybe You should open another question like "Queries working slower in JPA" or some similar question if no one helps You here.